# Android NDK compilation error. No such file error for the file already there

Tags: android, android-ndk-r5

Hi I want help to work with android NDK.

I have set up my eclipse Helios to work with NDK with help of [this](http://codemaemo.appforce.org/2010/07/tutorial-using-eclipse-for-ndk-projects/) tutorial. I am using windows. When trying to build I am shown this error

```
 make[1]: Entering directory 
`/cygdrive/d/WorkSpace/TestProject/TestProject'
    /cygdrive/d/DevTools/android-ndk-r5b-windows/android-ndk-r5b/build/core/build-local.mk:39: build/core/init.mk: No such file or directory
    make[1]: Leaving directory 
`/cygdrive/d/WorkSpace/TestProject/TestProject'
    /cygdrive/d/DevTools/android-ndk-r5b-windows/android-ndk-r5b/build/core/build-local.mk:76: *** missing `endif'.  Stop.
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It doesn't let me build my application.

How to solve this error?

**EDIT** :  I have tried to build hello-jni application with the eclipse and cygwin but I couldn't build the program, it throws same error

Comment: looks like a bad build file...?  does the missing file actually exist?

Comment: are you on Windows or Linux?  I remember this being a common issue with the toolchain on Windows not being the same as the toolchain in Linux

Comment: As written ....tutorial. I am using `windows`. When....

Comment: `I had the same problem last week. You have to download xcode and get the UNIX developer package. After I did that it worked fine!` says someone in the comments of that page

Comment: Read the comment where james [who posted the problem] said he is on MAC OS X.... and xcode is only for mac os, how will it help me on windows?

Comment: what version `make` are you using

Comment: Dr. J I have realized my make version was wrong.... upgraded cygwin and things are working like a charm.... by the way my make version was 3.80.... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the mistake.... Actually the make command was older than the recommended version. That was the reason why none of the ndk was running properly. I have upgraded the make version and everything is running the way it should.... even that eclipse tutorial is running like a charm......

TIP: You may have that old cygwin with you... you may still find it useful which have make v 3.80.... upgrade it from internet for version 3.81 and it will work.